# Wrap Featured Image in a Link

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want to wrap a link around a featured image (only if the custom meta box has been filled in), the link will come from a custom meta box.

Here's my image code: `the_post_thumbnail('screenshot');`

Here's my code for displaying the link using text:

```
<?php //Only if $urllink is filled in, display this link. ?>
  <?php $urlbox = get_url_desc_box();
    if ( !empty( $urlbox[0] ) ) {
      echo sprintf( '<a target="_blank" href="%s">Visit Website &raquo;</a>', $urlbox[0] );
} ?>
```

I've tried a few ways to get this to work but can't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there's some part of your problem I don't grasp, what's wrong with a simple mash-up of the two given snippets?

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $urlbox = get_url_desc_box();
    $post_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'screenshot' );
    if( !empty( $urlbox[0] ) && !empty( $post_thumb ) ) {
        echo sprintf( '<a target="_blank" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', $urlbox[0], $post_thumb );
    }
?>
```

**Edited: [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) vs. [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)**

In accordance to the general WP function naming convention, `the_post_thumbnail` echoes/displays the image, whereas `get_the_post_thumbnail` returns it.
In addition to that, `the_post_thumbnail` can only be used inside the Loop, while `get_the_post_thumbnail` takes one further parameter, the post ID. The two optional paramters after the ID are identical to those of `the_post_thumbnail`.

Hence, you can use `get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'screenshot' )` to preserve your size settings.

Comment: I've tried your code snippet above Johannes, but the image does not appear, the link does if you peek at the source code.

Comment: Sry, didn't check the nature of `get_the_post_thumbnail` --> Needs to be fed the post ID. Edited.

Comment: Image now displays, thank you. But it's not at the set width & height. 'the_post_thumbnail('screenshot');'

Comment: See 2nd edit. `get_the_post_thumbnail` also takes the `$size` paramter.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for your help. Works a treat. Thank you.